# How to increase the size of apps interface

Tags: fonts, window, window-manager, interface

I'm completely new to linux & Ubuntu so sorry if this seems trivial.
I noticed that within some apps like Spotify, the interface is tiny compared to the size of the window (see image).
So I wondered if someone could have a solution for this issue because it's very difficult for me to read or see anything.

*Exemple of the issue with Spotify:*

[image]

Thanks in advance for you time and answers.

Answer (score 2):

It's pobably to late for an answer but if you want to increase the interface size for spotify for everytime you start it you have to add some text to the launcher file of spotify. Depending on how you installed it the location of the "Starter" can vary. But what stas the same is the line you have to add:

```
--force-device-scale-factor=2
```

so that part has to go between the spotify and the %U like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]

X-SnapInstanceName=spotify

Type=Application

Name=Spotify

GenericName=Music Player

Icon=/snap/spotify/43/usr/share/spotify/icons/spotify-linux-128.png

Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/spotify_spotify.desktop /snap/bin/spotify --force-device-scale-factor=2 %U

Terminal=false

MimeType=x-scheme-handler/spotify;

Categories=Audio;Music;Player;AudioVideo;

StartupWMClass=spotify
```

Answer (score 0):

[Spotify](https://www.spotify.com/us/download/linux/) says it's not a supported app: *Spotify for Linux is a labor of love from our engineers that wanted to listen to Spotify on their Linux development machines. They work on it in their spare time and it is currently not a platform that we actively support. The experience may differ from our other Spotify Desktop clients, such as Windows and Mac. You can tell us what you think and ask other users for help at the Desktop (Linux) board in the Spotify Community forum.* https://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Linux/bd-p/desktop_linux

From the look of it, it appears as if they just took their Android app and did the least possible to make it work in Linux.

Comment: Ok good to know ! Thanks a lot

Comment: How i that good to know? Good to know they did a half baked job?